# PHP Session variable not persisting across pages

Tags: php, ajax, session-variables

I'm working on a web app. After a user logs in, a `$_SESSION` variable named `user` should be stored. However, when I try to access it later I am unable to.

Both login.php and settings.php are accessed via AJAX and displayed in a modal window.

**login.php:**

```
<?PHP
require("require/connect.php"); 
$errors = array();
$passed=FALSE;
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
     /* Check db, no output */
     if($record->password != $password){ ?>
          /* Output login fail message */
     <?PHP }else if(intval($record->confirmed)!=1){ ?>
          /* Output email not cofirmed message */
     <?PHP }else{ ?>
         $user = clone $record;
         unset($user->password);
         session_start();
         $_SESSION['user']=$user;
         print_r($_SESSION);
         /*output success message*/
     <?PHP }; 
}else{ /*output login form*/ } ?>
```

prints out:

**settings.php**

```
<?PHP
require("require/connect.php");
require("require/userdata.php");
/*other stuff*//
```

**require/userdata.php**

```
<?PHP session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

prints out:

```
Array ( )
```

Comment: Place `session_start()` at the top of your code, just to avoid any issues

Comment: `session_start()` needs to be before any output is generated, even white-spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In login.php I had to move `session_start()` above `require("require/connect.php");`. Even the directly next line didn't work.

Not sure why this changed anything, since connect.php is only too lines and no output.

**connect.php**

```
<?PHP 
mysql_connect(/**/)or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL database");    
mysql_select_db(/**/) or die("Couldn't select MySQL database in connect.php");
?>
```

Comment: a space after closing PHP tag. You desperately need to turn error reporting on.